# how to get form values in php without submitting a form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, seo

I am using form submition in my old site.Because of SEO purpose I changed this to onClick() function,So that it will go to a clean URL but when I am using this function other form values are not getting in the php file

Below is my Old code

```
 <form name="frmSearchTops" id="frmSearchTops" action="/womens/tops/" method="post">
        <select  name="cboCityNameRes" id="cboCityNameRes">
          <option value=''>City</option>
             {foreach from= $arritemCities item=foo}                      
               {if $smarty.post.hdnCityName eq $foo}                                
                  <option value="{$foo}" selected="selected">{$foo}</option>          
               {else}    
                <option value="{$foo}" {if $foo eq 'City'} selected="selected"{/if}>
                     {$foo}
                </option>
               {/if}    
             {/foreach}    
        </select>
    <select name="cboMaterial" id="cboMaterial">
      <option value="">Material</option>
      <option value="CT">Cotton</option>
      <option value="SL">Silk</option>
    </select>
     <input name="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>       
 </form>
```

new code is the below one
here I am giving a dummy URL in controller action it will redirect to womens/tops.php file its redirecting but I am not getting the selected type of material

JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

          function searchitem()
          {
        $strCity    =   document.getElementById('cboCityNameRes').value;
        window.location.href = "http://www.legacy.com/womens-tops-"+$strCity+".php";
          }
    </script>
```

HTML Code

```
 <select  name="cboCityNameRes" id="cboCityNameRes" onchange="cityChanged()">
      <option value=''>City</option>                  
       {foreach from= $arritemCities item=foo}                        
          {if $smarty.post.hdnCityName eq $foo}                                 
             <option value="{$foo}" selected="selected">{$foo} </option>                      
          {else}    
             <option value="{$foo}" {if $foo eq 'City'} selected="selected"{/if}>
                 {$foo} 
            </option> 
          {/if} 
        {/foreach}    
    </select>                        
   <select name="cboMaterial" id="cboMaterial">
     <option value="">Material</option>
     <option value="CT">Cotton</option>
     <option value="SL">Silk</option>
   </select>                    
    <input name="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onclick="searchitem()"/>
```

Comment: How is it possible to get the values before it get posted

Comment: once form submit the values will get.Same way after onclick i want to do

Comment: What do you mean by "other form values are not getting in the php file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do window.location like that you're redirecting the page and this is a GET request not a POST.

You'd need to add the extra variables to a query string e.g.

window.location.href = "http://www.legacy.com/womens-tops-" + strCity +".php?something=blah";

And then something would be blah in the PHP called.

Another easier way is to use jQuery (or plain JavaScript if you prefer) to change the action of the form so that the path was your "womens-tops-$strCity" and then submit the form.

```
var strCity = document.getElementById('cboCityNameRes').value;
var frm = document.getElementById('frmSearchTops')
frm.action = "/womens-tops-" + strCity + ".php";
frm.submit();
```

Or jQuery

```
var strCity = $('#cboCityNameRes').val();
$("#frmSearchTops").attr("action", "/womens-tops-" + strCity + ".php");
$("#frmSearchTops").submit();
```

Though search engine robots aren't going to run any JavaScript at all. So this isn't really doing anything for you with SEO. At least as far as I can see from your example. You may have some other reason to do this though so the answer still stands.

Comment: I am sorry its resubmitting to same page

Comment: <form name="frmSearchTops" id="frmSearchTops" action="" method="post">  in action i am passing null and without action also i tried

Comment: if you set action to nothing it will post to the same page... You have to set action to the URL you want to go to. Like I showed in my answer.

Comment: In your answer  you are given javascript action i am asking about form tag action

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Suddenly my internet got disconnected thats y

Comment: My answer is the form tags action. Not Javascript action (not sure what you mean by that). You need to set the action to the URL you want for SEO (like I showed in the JavaScript) then submit the form. And you'll be golden. I highly recommend using jQuery though (2nd example).

Comment: In html code <form name="frmSearchTops" id="frmSearchTops" action="/womens/tops/" method="post"> here in action what i want to give

Comment: its working fine in Firefox but in Chrome still its not working

Comment: I modified my answer with better code. Its now using the forms ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a select with the onchange event calling the function `cityChanged` yet you only posted the function `searchitem`.

Nevertheless, you can pass the value selected for a select doing something like:

```
<select  name="cboCityNameRes" id="cboCityNameRes" onchange="cityChanged(this.value)">
...
</select>
```

then using the value of the function argument with something like:

```
function cityChanged(city){
    var material = document.getElementById("cboMaterial").options[document.getElementById("cboMaterial").selectedIndex].value;
    // window.location.href = "http://www.legacy.com/womens-tops-"+city+".php"
    // add material to the URL somewhere?
}
```

Comment: no i am not asking this In my form user can select city and  material and when they click search button it will submit the form.(this is the old one). But I changed this to onClick of the button I am calling a function in that I am going to the specific url

Comment: i cant't add material in URL because i need clean URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cityChanged(val) {
var value = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;  
window.location.href = "http://www.legacy.com/womens-tops-"+value+".php";
}
```

and your HTML should be like this,

```
<select  name="cboCityNameRes" id="cboCityNameRes" onchange="cityChanged(this)">
```

hope this works for you

Comment: i am getting city but material is not getting to next page

Comment: yepee , you got the value , not do a little work to sort this thing out or let me know what you are getting